# Which sentence to use for save my name and email checkbox?

Tags: checkboxes, text

Which sentence would be more clear and correct:

- “Save my name and email for my next comments”,
- “Save my name and email for my future comments”,
- “Save my name and email”,
- “Save entered data for my next comments”,
- Your variant with describing why exactly it.

?

Sentence will be used in the comment form of the website. This is the label of the checkbox. The comment form contains three inputs: name, email address and message. The context is saving user's data for automatic input of them in the comment form at next time, when user will want to publish comment. After commenting, name and message will be published, email will not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would go with "Remember" instead of "Save". The data **is** being saved, but so is the current comment. "Remember" has the connotation of "make it easier for me the next time".

**Remember my name and email for future comments**

Comment: "Remember my name and email"

Comment: @manassehkatz, which do you think would be better:
“Remember my name and email for future comments” or “Remember my name and email” (the variant of @SergeyKirienko)?

Comment: “Remember my name and email for future comments” - because it is a given that your name & email are being remembered (aka "saved") now - i.e., the web site will know who you are. "for future comments" makes it clear what the checkbox is for. "Remember my name and email" might be construed to mean "if I check this box then my name & email will be posted and if I do **NOT** check this box then my comment will be **anonymous**" which is a very different meaning.

Comment: @manassehkatz, could you clarify, why to use “future” instead of  “next”?

Comment: "future" means "one or more". "next" could imply "only the next one and after that I have 'save' again"

Comment: @manassehkatz, the same goes for “following comments”?

Comment: I think 'future' is clearer than 'following'. 'following', to me, more typically means an 'immediate' set of information - e.g., more on the same page.